# Different results from similar methods

Tags: java, math

In my class I tried to return the sum of: `2^n + 2^(n+1) + 2^(n+2) ...` in 2 ways.
Iterative in the first method and recursive in the 2nd one.

This worked as long as numbers weren't too big. Can someone explain to me why those methods return different answers when used with high numbers?

```
public class Power
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        System.out.println(iterativ(3));
        System.out.println(rekursiv(3));

        System.out.println(iterativ(40));
        // The recursive one is lower by 10
        System.out.println(rekursiv(40));
    }

    public static int iterativ(int x)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
            sum += Math.pow(2, i);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static int rekursiv(int x)
    {           
        if (x > 0) {
            return ((int) Math.pow(2, x) + rekursiv(x - 1));
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: "And I also want to know which one gives me always the right answer." - I'd guess that's your job ;) - Edit: just saw your code basically contains the example I asked for.

Comment: Debugger and `println()`s are your best friends here!

Comment: Try your code with `double` instead of `int` for at least one obvious reason: the maximum value for `int` is 2^31-1 which clearly is lower than 2^40 which you are trying. Thus you'll get an overflow with `int`. `double` is able to still represent those values albeit with some loss of precision. Alternatively use `long` which allows for values up to 2^63-1 (i.e. your code should work up to x = 62).

Comment: Another option: instead of `(int) Math.pow(2, x)` use integer operation - binary left shift of 1

Comment: Thx for the answer :) That actually wasnt my job though, i m just learning for an exam and wanted to go the easy way :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using functions that deal with `double`. You are casting your values to `int`. Casting values will sooner or later always lead to some inaccurate results, even more so, if you cast from `double` to `int`.

The number you were seeing when using `40` as your exponent, was `2147483647`, which is in fact `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, but isn't `2^40`. It is rather `2^31-1`. The java tutorial has a chapter about [the primitive datatypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), which shows you the ranges of each type.

Besides using `double` you may also want to look at [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.